# UIDs in Gmail - per "folder" or unique per user account?

Tags: python, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I recently began using the [IMAPClient package](https://pypi.org/project/IMAPClient/) in an app where I had previously used `imaplib`. Something broke after a long time away from the code base (long enough that I was going from Python 2 to Python 3), and I wasn't up for wading into IMAP4 gore (again). I decided to search for something a bit higher level. IMAPClient has, for the most part, been an improvement.

Looking at the [docs](https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/), I came across this (emphasis mine):

> In the IMAP protocol, messages are identified using an integer. These message ids are
> **specific to a given folder**.

I have been using UIDs, operating under the assumption that they are unique across all messages within the account, not per-folder (or per-label for Gmail). This might have been a mistake. Should I instead be considering them to be per-folder? How would that work when talking to Gmail, whose labels aren't exactly the same as folders?

Let me take this from the hypothetical to the concrete. Consider the message with Message-ID `<python/cpython/pull/24293@github.com>` to which I have applied two labels, `polly` and `python/github`. IMAP4 treats these labels as if they are folders. Will Gmail associate one UID or two with that message? If I search first `polly`, then `python/github` I assume something representing that message will be returned twice. Will it have the same UID or not?

I found this bit of [Gmail-specific IMAP4 documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions), but it seems to be mum on the topic.

Comment: It is the same as standard: there is one UID per _instance_ of the message, per folder.  UIDs are only valid for a (folder-UIDVALIDITY) tuple.  If you need a globally unique identifier, that is what the extension X-GM-MSGID is for.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just save a (foldername, uid) tuple to insure I don't miss some messages. While I'm just a dumb Gmail user, I'd prefer not to use Gmail extensions if possible.

Comment: Are you using the [Gmail IMAP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp) libraries to send these emails?

Comment: I'm not sending mail at all. I'm just building a personal dictionary using some of my mail (those sent to a few public mailing lists I subscribe to, nothing personal) for feeding into a password generator based on XKCD 936. The idea isn't mine. It is based on a similar system another person built using a bot to build a dictionary from chit chat in an online adventure game.

Comment: Hi ! So what is your application exactly doing? Retrieving your mail from your inbox and then ordering it depending on the mail Id? Could you share a minimal reproducible code with no sensitive data? And your porblem is that you dont know how Gmail message Ids are structured to order them?

Comment: Not really a minimal example, but my application, polly, is on Github: https://github.com/smontanaro/polly It is used to construct a dictionary from suitably tagged email messages. That dictionary is then used as input to a modified XKCD 936 password generator. The README file is probably a bit outdated, but gives more detail.